# Angular 13 bundle size

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, node-modules, webpack-bundle-analyzer

The bundle dist size of my Angular13.1.1 project is big (3.5mega to download for users).
I could gzip or lazyLoad some parts, but I am wondering if my bundle is normal, because in webpack-bundle-analyzer I see per example several places with node_modules

[image]

Is my bundle fine?

I try to reduce bundle size by removing imports and changing angular configuration but I would like to have an external opinion

Comment: This is a very open question, hard to answer just like that... If you said your app was an hello world page, then I'd say it is a little big. If it is a , let's say, discord app clone, then it looks ok...

Comment: you want to say that for discord clone 3.5m - must be enough? Maby as MVP...

Comment: just checked in browser - 
2.5 MB / 4.9 MB transferred - but it's gzipped - so on discord channels page approximately 10 MB - as I understand...

Comment: Ok thank you guys. If you say nothing looks too wrong then this is ok. And after using gzip and adding the right conf to my apache file, then project have a very acceptable transfer size.
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
.....